# The Blender Image Editor's zooming feature has rough filtering than other 2D software

Tags: uv-image-editor, 2d

I loaded an image to the image editor for reference and scaled for fit my screen it.
And I got pretty rough filtered view.
Other 2D software shows smooth filtering.
To help you understand rough filtering, I filmed comparative GIFs on Blender, Photoshop, Krita, and TVPaint Animation.
Is there any option I missed on the blender? Or is it the limit of the blender's image editor?
I used Blender 2.92

Blender
[image]

Photoshop
[image]

Krita
[image]

Tvpaint Animation
[image]